# How to break Monthly Budget by each day SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE 
            (
                Amount MONEY, 
                InsurType VARCHAR(100), 
                MonthNumber INT, 
                PostDate DATETIME, 
                DaysInMonth INT
            )

INSERT INTO @TempTable 
VALUES (2019317, 'Commercial Auto', 1, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31),
       (3757832, 'Commercial Auto', 2, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 28),
       (5010746, 'Commercial Auto', 3, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31),
       (4461429.66, 'Commercial Auto', 4, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 30),
       (4049404.44, 'Commercial Auto', 5, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31)

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

Result looks like that:

[image]

Is it possible to break down the amount by each day of the month for all 5 months?

For example the `Amount` for `MonthNumber` 1 is = $2,019,317 / 31 = $65,139 per day.

The output should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just inner join with `(VALUES (1), ..., (31))`. You cannot have more than 31 days in a month so it is easier to type them.

```
SELECT Amount / DaysInMonth, InsurType, MonthNumber, days.d
FROM @TempTable
INNER JOIN (VALUES
    (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29), (30), (31)
) AS days(d) ON days.d <= DaysInMonth
```

Comment: Also an option.   I wonder how this performs compared to a indexed "numbers" table.   Probably pretty close since an index probably doesn't add that much to a numbers table.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy really.   Just join to a numbers table on the number being equal or less than the number of days in the month, and the amount is just the total divided by the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

With a tally table as an additional option for the table constructor.

```
create table #TempTable  
            (
            Amount Money, 
            InsurType varchar(100), 
            MonthNumber int, 
            PostDate datetime, 
            DaysInMonth int
            )
        INSERT INTO #TempTable values (2019317,'Commercial Auto', 1, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',31 ),
                                        (3757832,'Commercial Auto', 2, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',28 ),
                                        (5010746,'Commercial Auto', 3, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',31 ),
                                        (4461429.66,'Commercial Auto', 4, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',30 ),
                                        (4049404.44,'Commercial Auto', 5, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',31 )


;WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
    cteTally(N) AS ( SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2)



select * 
from #TempTable t 
inner join cteTally on cteTally.N <= t.DaysInMonth
order by Amount, N

drop table #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a system table of static number values to use. Throwing this answer into the mix, pick your poison.

```
select number from master..spt_values d
where d.type = 'p'
and d.number between 1 and 31

select Amount/cast(DaysInMonth as money) DailyAmt,  InsurType, MonthNumber, d.number Day
from @TempTable t
join master..spt_values d on d.number <= t.DaysInMonth
and d.number between 1 and 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tally table option (using MS SQL Server 2016)

To get this result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
;with TempTable AS(
SELECT
2019317 AS Amount, 'Commercial Auto' AS InsurType, 1 AS MonthNumber, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS PostDate, 31 AS DaysInMonth
UNION ALL SELECT 3757832, 'Commercial Auto', 2, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 28
UNION ALL SELECT 5010746, 'Commercial Auto', 3, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31
UNION ALL SELECT 4461429.66, 'Commercial Auto', 4, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 30
UNION ALL SELECT 4049404.44, 'Commercial Auto', 5, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31
)

,Tally AS(
SELECT top 31
    rn = Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM sys.objects
)

SELECT
    TempTable.*,
    rn AS DayNum,
    MonthlyAmount           = round(cast(TempTable.amount / TempTable.DaysInMonth as money), 0)

FROM TempTable
    cross join Tally

where 
DaysInMonth = rn
--rn <= DaysInMonth

Order by MonthNumber, rn
```

To get this other result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
 ;with TempTable AS(
    SELECT
    2019317 AS Amount, 'Commercial Auto' AS InsurType, 1 AS MonthNumber, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS PostDate, 31 AS DaysInMonth
    UNION ALL SELECT 3757832, 'Commercial Auto', 2, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 28
    UNION ALL SELECT 5010746, 'Commercial Auto', 3, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31
    UNION ALL SELECT 4461429.66, 'Commercial Auto', 4, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 30
    UNION ALL SELECT 4049404.44, 'Commercial Auto', 5, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 31
    )

,Tally AS(
SELECT top 31
    rn = Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM sys.objects
)

SELECT
    TempTable.*,
    rn AS DayNum,
    MonthlyAmount           = round(cast(TempTable.amount / TempTable.DaysInMonth as money), 0)

FROM TempTable
    cross join Tally



 where 
    --DaysInMonth = rn
    rn <= DaysInMonth

    Order by MonthNumber, rn
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you are storing the month number and days in month? You can determine that easy enough using SQL:

```
DECLARE @Nums TABLE(num int)

;WITH nums AS
   (SELECT 1 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value + 1 AS value
    FROM nums
    WHERE nums.value <= 31)
insert @Nums
SELECT *
FROM nums

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE 
            (
                Amount MONEY, 
                InsurType VARCHAR(100), 
                PostDate DATETIME
            )

INSERT INTO @TempTable 
VALUES (2019317, 'Commercial Auto A', '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (3757832, 'Commercial Auto B', '2018-02-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (5010746, 'Commercial Auto C', '2018-03-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (4461429.66, 'Commercial Auto D', '2018-04-01 00:00:00.000'),
       (4049404.44, 'Commercial Auto E', '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000')

SELECT (Amount / DAY(EOMONTH(PostDate))) as DailyAmount, InsurType, 
    datepart(month, PostDate) as TheMonth, n.num as TheDay
FROM @TempTable tt
    JOIN @Nums n ON n.num <= DAY(EOMONTH(PostDate))
ORDER BY datepart(month, PostDate)
```